# How to connect a USB Device to Bluestack

Tags: applications, usb, bluestacks

I have drone( DJI Phantom 3), and in order to fly it correctly DJI provides an App for IOS and Android("DJI Go"). The thing is that I have a Kolina k100 android phone(a cheap chineese one), and I can install the app perfectly, and it runs quite well with an only exception. When I put the Drone on video-recording mode, I loose the live-video and I can not see what my drone sees. Obviously DJI has told me that he doesn't support my chinese phone so they do nothing. So I was thinking that maybe is a problem of how powerful my phone is.

So I wanted to check if the App works well in my laptop so I downloaded the app in Bluestacks, but I realised that to make the app work I have to connect the drone's RC controller by USB (as I do with my phone). But when I connect the controller to the  laptop, Windows recognizes it. But Bluestack doesn't care so the app doesnt work. How can I make Bluestack recognize the USB connection of the controller?

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.